# Parsing XML data stored in a varchar for all the values that match and give the sum of these values

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that is storing some XML data in a varchar field in a table. This is used to represent a trip in an asp.net page and so I need a way of taking that data and summing all the cost values to get the total cost of the value.

The XML string is amongst dozens of others. There can be a number of matching strings. It says the following,

------------Updated XML schema added with an edit-------

```
<trip>
   <toolboxitemadded id="8ce489fa-acb7-40e9-8440-cad46e16ca65" class="ToolBoxItemAdded" version="1">
    <control id="Location" type="text" value="Mattison, LLC-David Taylor" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Description" value="Mattison, LLC&#xA;PO Box 7137&#xA;Statesville, NC 28687, United States&#xA;Tel:704-838-1991 Ext 209&#xA;E-Mail:david@mattison-consulting.com" tag="TEXTAREA" />
       <control id="Visibility_Customer" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Visibility_Bidder" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Visibility_Status" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Reserved_expires" type="text" value="7/22/2012 17:47" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Reserved_contacts" type="hidden" value="2366" tag="INPUT" />
   </toolboxitemadded>
   <toolboxitemadded id="8a19f19b-79a8-4d1a-a12c-a4378160116e" class="ToolBoxItemAdded" version="1">
       <control id="TypeOfItem" value="Pallet" tag="SELECT" />
       <control id="NumberOfItems" type="text" value="4" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Description" value="Some cool stuff" tag="TEXTAREA" />
       <control id="BreaksDown" type="checkbox" value="false" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Length" type="text" value="48" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Width" type="text" value="48" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Height" type="text" value="48" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Weight" type="text" value="2000" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="MeasurementType" value="Standard" tag="SELECT" />
       <control id="Hazmat" type="checkbox" value="false" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="UNCode" type="text" value="" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="ClassCode" type="text" value="" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Visibility_Customer" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Visibility_Bidder" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
       <control id="Visibility_Status" type="checkbox" value="false" tag="INPUT" />
  </toolboxitemadded>
  <toolboxitemadded id="ae33c118-2981-4a3e-b001-c6dc56d0e7f1" class="ToolBoxItemAdded" version="1">
    <control id="AirportName" type="text" value="KCLT" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="ICAO" type="text" value="KCLT" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="IATA" type="text" value="CLT" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Address" value="Charlotte" tag="TEXTAREA" />
    <control id="Description" value="" tag="TEXTAREA" />
    <control id="Visibility_Customer" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Visibility_Bidder" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Visibility_Status" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_expires" type="text" value="7/22/2012 17:48" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_cost" type="text" value="15000" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_markup" type="text" value="" tag="INPUT" />
  </toolboxitemadded>
  <toolboxitemadded id="4aea1ef1-e0fd-482c-9d64-217b7f891e61" class="ToolBoxItemAdded" version="1">
    <control id="Description" type="text" value="Falcon test 3" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="TailNumber" type="text" value="MP123D" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="FlightNumber" type="text" value="12334" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Carrier" type="text" value="[object Object]" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Model" type="text" value="Desault Falcon 20" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="AircraftNotes" value="Some aircraft" tag="TEXTAREA" />
    <control id="Visibility_Customer" type="checkbox" value="false" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Visibility_Bidder" type="checkbox" value="false" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Visibility_Status" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_cost" type="text" value="20000" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_markup" type="text" value="" tag="INPUT" />
  </toolboxitemadded>
  <toolboxitemadded id="ae33c118-2981-4a3e-b001-c6dc56d0e7f1" class="ToolBoxItemAdded" version="1">
    <control id="AirportName" type="text" value="ATL" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="ICAO" type="text" value="KATL" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="IATA" type="text" value="ATL" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Address" value="Atlanta" tag="TEXTAREA" />
    <control id="Description" value="" tag="TEXTAREA" />
    <control id="Visibility_Customer" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Visibility_Bidder" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Visibility_Status" type="checkbox" value="true" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_expires" type="text" value="7/22/2012 17:48" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_cost" type="text" value="22000" tag="INPUT" />
    <control id="Reserved_markup" type="text" value="" tag="INPUT" />
  </toolboxitemadded>
```

------------Updated XML schema added with an edit-------

Thats not all the code but there should be plenty there to understand how it been put together,

I need to parse every single instance of this xml string from the field and then take the values and add them altogether, so that a report can give the total price of the trip, but I have no real idea how this would be done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like XML so with a bit of luck you can cast your `varchar` column to XML and sum in a XQuery expression while fetching the value.

```sql
declare @T table
(
  Cost nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @T values
('<control id="Reserved_cost" type="text" value="20000" tag="INPUT" /><control id="Reserved_cost" type="text" value="20000" tag="INPUT" />'),
('<control id="Reserved_cost" type="text" value="20000" tag="INPUT" />')

select cast(T.Cost as xml).value('sum(//control/@value)', 'int') as CostSum
from @T as T
```

Result:

```
CostSum
-----------
40000
20000
```

**Update:**

You can add a predicate between square brackets in the XQuery.
Use this to sum only the nodes where attribute `id` has the value `Reserved_cost`.

```
select cast(T.Cost as xml).value('sum(//control[@id="Reserved_cost"]/@value)', 'int') as CostSum
from @T as T
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am afraid I dumbed down my xml way too much so this will not work for my case, but I learned alot from your post. Any help on how I would get all the values from the Reserved_cost in the xml and the sum would be nice indeed.